# Orientation for only single screen in cordova iOS app

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using 'screen.lockOrientation("portrait")' for my cordova iOS application. 
Now from one plugin I want to display one UIViewController. The code for that as follows:

```
[self.viewController presentViewController:self.myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I want to allow both orientation for this viewcontroller, but this view supports only portrait.

How I can support orientation for only one screen (UIViewController) added from the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the orientation property in the xib of your controller (if you have it) to landscape. As it is a viewController, you should have **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation** method, so you can set the orientation here as well.

Comment: Yes i have xib. So from xib I have selected "Landscape" in the Orientation. and I have also tried with shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation return yes method but still I can see it in portrait mode only. I have also tried by adding that view controller on appDelegate.window but not working.